# I am not able to use sudo-apt upgrade whenever i try this error shows up like this how can i fix it?

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi-os

```
$ sudo apt upgrade

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  libfuse2 raspinfo

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kms++-utils raspi-utils

The following packages will be upgraded:
  base-files bind9-host bind9-libs curl dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11
  distro-info-data git git-man isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common libbluray2
  libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdbus-1-3 libde265-0 libexpat1 libexpat1-dev
  libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libk5crypto3
  libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libksba8 libmaven-shared-utils-java libnftables1
  libntfs-3g883 libopenexr25 libpq5 libtasn1-6 libtiff5 libuv1 libvncclient1
  libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libxml2 nano nftables ntfs-3g openjdk-11-jdk-headless
  openjdk-11-jre-headless raspinfo sudo tzdata
45 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 243 MB/244 MB of archives.

After this operation, 8,718 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf dbus armhf 1.12.24-0+deb11u1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libdbus-1-3 armhf 1.12.24-0+deb11u1
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

Err:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libexpat1-dev armhf 2.2.10-2+deb11u5
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

Err:4 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf libexpat1 armhf 2.2.10-2+deb11u5
  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/d/dbus/dbus_1.12.24-0+deb11u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-3_1.12.24-0+deb11u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/o/openjdk-11/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.18+10-1~deb11u1_armhf.deb  Connection failed [IP: 103.195.68.3 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Try again, you've had a transient connection error.

Answer (score 5):

Change the repository server by editing below file using

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Try another repository from the list given in
https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors

change the below line with the new repository :

deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ bullseye main contrib non-free rpi

Comment: I tried it but it takes too much time to download from those servers I mean it takes days to download. I am from india which sever should I choose for fast download. I tried one two Asian but they also show the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I changed default Mirror
`deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi` to

```
deb https://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

in

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.
I also changed the `http:// to https://` in the new mirror because it didn't worked with `http://`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved, I face the same issue: following are the steps:

1. change your location to GB
2. change the repository to http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian
3. restart the system
4. Try upgrade